# Flutter: On Tap of each seat number, I need the seat number from following image

Tags: flutter, dart, onclick

I want to make every seat clickable from this Image
Is there any way we can achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Please try to add your code snippet. if its index then try `print(index);`

Comment: It is just an image.

Comment: convert it to svg, with raw raster image like png or jpg it is impossible, for some inspiration check https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add every seat clickable from this Image. but method is very complex. here some tips you can try for make clickable.

- 1.Wrap image to stack
- 2.Add Sizebox or Container (set default height and width & set transplant color).
- 3.Set every size box or container to where you want click .
- 4.For set box you use Positioned widget.
- 5.Now you click all seats

Comment: But how I will click the round corner seats?

Comment: Simple use rotated box & and give you some box height and width as you want .